# Using AJAX to get JSON and use response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is my AJAX...

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../getSynd.php",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(jsVar){
    document.write(jsVar['sysinfo'][0]);
    syndStatus("canvas1", "first server name", "76","red");
    syndStatus("canvas2", "second server name", "1.2423","green");
  }
});
```

And my JSON from getSynd.php is as follows...

```
[{"sysinfo":"server1","result":"1.17805935"},{"sysinfo":"server2","result":"2069.59799893"}]
```

How do I get the sysinfo/result out of jsVar?

EDIT:
I figured it out, thanks to everyone here!

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../getSynd.php",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(jsVar){

    syndStatus("canvas1", jsVar[0]['sysinfo'], jsVar[0]['result']);
    syndStatus("canvas1", jsVar[1]['sysinfo'], jsVar[1]['result']);
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to do more research into handling AJAX and JSON responses. The language you use ("save into JavaScript variables") indicates this. In particular, look into jQuery's `$.getJSON` and the native `JSON.parse()`

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: I have tried, and this is what became of it. Thanks for the "helpful" response.

Comment: use `document.write(jsVar[0]['sysinfo']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using `dataType` param in ajax, you will be getting the response already parsed as javascript variable. You just need to capture it in success callback of ajax call like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jsVar) {
       //jsVar will be the javascript array
    }
});
```

Comment: No. `dataType:"json",` will make jQuery parse it before it even gives you the data.

Comment: I'm confused how the success function part works... is the data stored in jsVar? I'm super new to web and javascript.

Comment: yes... when ajax call returns successfully without any errors (like network issues, timeouts etc), the success callback is called automatically, and the response from ajax is saved in the variable 'jsVar' (you can name it whatever you want).

Comment: Okay, so how do I pull out the data saved in jsVar... it looks like "[object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: You are trying to `document.write` the array. Your array contains objects, so you are seeing [object Object] ... Iterate over the array using any looping construct, and inside each iteration, access the current object's properties like myObj.sysinfo, myObj.result (myObj is the object during current iteration of loop). Cannot be more detailed. Try it. Google is your friend.

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "../getSynd.php",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(jsVar){

    syndStatus("canvas1", jsVar[0]['sysinfo'], jsVar[0]['result']);
    syndStatus("canvas1", jsVar[1]['sysinfo'], jsVar[1]['result']);
  }
});